# Response not submitted when rxEnd is used in HTTP server

Tags: vert.x

I have a two verticle server written in vert.x + reactive extensions. HTTP server verticle uses event bus to send requests to the DB verticle. After receiving the response from the DB verticle (through event bus) I send the response to the http client using rxEnd. However clients does not seem to receive this response and times out eventually. If I were to use end() instead, things work fine. I use postman to test this REST API. Please see below for the code which forward results from the DB verticle to client.

```
routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId("createChargePoints", routingContext -> {
            RequestParameters params = routingContext.get("parsedParameters");

            RequestParameter body = params.body();
            JsonObject jsonBody = body.getJsonObject();

            vertx.eventBus().rxRequest("dbin", jsonBody)
                    .map(message -> {
                        System.out.println(message.body());
                        return routingContext.response().setStatusCode(200).rxEnd(message.body().toString());
                    })
                    .subscribe(res -> {
                        System.out.println(res);
                    }, res -> {
                        System.out.println(res);
                    });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rxEnd` method is a variant of `end` that returns a `Completable`. The former is *lazy*, the latter is not.

In other words, if you invoke `rxEnd` you have to subscribe to the `Completable` otherwise nothing happens.

Looking at the code of your snippet, I don't believe using `rxEnd` is necessary. Indeed, it doesn't seem like you need to know if the request was sent succesfully.

Comment: Cool, I think that is the problem, I need to subscribe to the observable! But could you explain why rxEnd is not necessary? is end() asynchronous?

Comment: It is not synchronous, in the sense that it will return even if all the content has not been sent yet to the client. So if you don't need to take action in case of sending failure, calling `end` is enough.